# EFQ - Sort by published date

Tags: database

I'm using the module [Publication Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/publication_date)  to store when nodes are published. It uses a simple table of nid and published_at for the timestamp. I need to use EFQ to sort nodes by this date, but I'm unsure if it's able to connect to the table it uses.

```
->propertyOrderBy('published_at', 'DESC');
```

obviously doesn't work.

Is there any way I can connect to this table using EFQ, or does it have to be a db_query?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done. You have to add a tag to your EFQ, for example:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->addTag('published_at')
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.
```

Then you wil have to implement hook_query_tag_alter, in your case:

```
function mymodule_query_published_at_alter($query){
  // Extend your query with some joins and order statements:
  $query->join('table');
  $query->orderBy('field');
}
```

The above code is an example, it won't work, but you get the picture :)